# Use source path from a list to aggregate costs from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following source path in the form of a `list` -

```
['node_A','node_B','node_C', 'node_D']
```

There are several other source paths and above one is just an example. `Node_B` is source for `node_A` and `node_C` is source for `node_B` and so on.

```
SOURCE  DESTINATION
node_B  node_A
node_C  node_B
node_D  node_C
```

I have a `dataframe` that has following columns -

```
source  destination cost_1  cost_2  cost_3  cost_4
node_B  node_A       1       5       7      5
node_C  node_B       3       1       2      1
node_D  node_C       1       5       1      5
node_Y  node_X       3       2       7      1
node_Z  node_Y       1       5       1      2
```

Based on my source path, I want to filter my `dataframe` on corresponding source and destination nodes and sum the costs for those pairs. For example, in above source path `['node_A','node_B','node_C', 'node_D']` I should get something like this -

```
source_path                                       cost_1  cost_2  cost_3  cost_4
['node_A','node_B','node_C', 'node_D']            5       11      10      11
```

I am able to accomplish this by filtering the `dataframe` based on source and destination pair (for each of the 3 pairs of the source path). I then append the 3 rows together and then do a sum over the cost. However this is taking considerable time. Is the an efficient way of doing this? If needed I can paste my code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` from list, [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with original, `sum` and last reshape for one row `DataFrame`:

```
L = ['node_A','node_B','node_C', 'node_D']

df1 = (pd.DataFrame({'source':L[1:], 'destination':L[:-1]})
         .merge(df)
         .drop('destination', 1)
         .sum()
         .to_frame()
         .T
         .assign(source=[L])
         .rename(columns={'source':'source_path'}))
print (df1)

                        source_path cost_1 cost_2 cost_3 cost_4
0  [node_A, node_B, node_C, node_D]      5     11     10     11
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `MultiIndex` to `reindex` df, and compute the sum.

```
src = ['node_A','node_B','node_C', 'node_D']
df = df.set_index(['source', 'destination'])

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(src[1:], src)))
df.reindex(idx).sum(0).to_frame(name=str(src)).T

                                          cost_1  cost_2  cost_3  cost_4
['node_A', 'node_B', 'node_C', 'node_D']       5      11      10      11
```